# No apex action available for class.method error

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, error, reference

I am getting a very weird error. My LWC Component is referencing two methods from an Apex class. Everything was working fine. Suddenly after a week,

I am getting this error: /{"message":"apex://CustomLogin: No apex action available for CustomLogin.transitionflagCheck"}/*ERROR*/

I am using this in my lwc:
import tryLogin from '@salesforce/apex/CustomLogin.login';

The same component was deployed to prod as well and it is working fine. Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: You should check the `CustomLogin` apex class to see if there are any changes (losing the `@auraEnabled` annotation, not being a static method, method name changed or method removed from the class, etc...)

Comment: You might also just need to recompile. If you can't see anything wrong, try just pushing a save that doesn't change anything.

Comment: @DerekF There is no change in Apex class at all.

Comment: @AdrianLarson works like a charm. Thank You so much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found when having this issue that causing the class to recompile will fix it. So just save the file again to force that to happen.

Answer (score 0):

FYI I ran through such an issue, where compiling resolved the problem. But the root cause  was a licence removal (at new year) that caused some metadata to be removed, meaning tables, table content and their metadata.
Indeed recompilation helped to "hide" the root cause avoiding unknown metadata to be called. But then correction had to be made (flexipage related lists removal, classes fix or such things).
Hope this helps.