# No apex action available for apex:class

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, permissions

I have an lwc that calls an apex method but somehow one of our prod users can access the initial method.

Profile and permission sets have access to the class and also any other kind of user can display this fine.

The class hasn't changed (neither the lwc).

Could it be something related to the users' license (Company Communities)?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here: [No apex action available for class.method error](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/352980/no-apex-action-available-for-class-method-error)

In simple words: If you try to recompile that class you will see, that something is wrong(for example dependent class was overwritten and the variable or method is not available anymore). So you need to fix that problem and recompile the class.